Does the dual group of a free abelian group separate subgroups?
Let $F$ be a free abelian group. Let $A,A' \subseteq F$ be two subgroups. Assume that for all $f \in F^* = \mathrm{Hom}(F,\mathbb{Z})$ we have $f(A) = f(A')$. Does this imply  $A = A'$?
Equivalently: If $A \subseteq F$ is a subgroup and $x \in F$ is such that $f(x) \in f(A)$ for all $f \in F^*$, do we have $x \in A$?
Of course, it is essential to assume that $F$ is free abelian. For example we have $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=0$ but many subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$.
I can prove this under the following assumption, which is known to be true when $F$ has finite rank by the structure theorem:
There is a basis $B$ of $F$, a subset $C \subseteq B$ and a function $u : C \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\{u(b) \cdot  b : c \in C\}$ is a basis of $A$. $(\ast)$
Then, for $b \in B$ we apply the hypothesis to the map $b^* \in F^*$ (defined by $b^*(b')=\delta_{b,b'}$). For $b \in B$ we get $b^*(x) \in b^*(A)$, which is $\mathbb{Z} \cdot u(b)$ for $b \in C$ and $0$ otherwise. Thus, $x = \sum_{b \in B} b^*(x) \cdot b \in \sum_{b \in C}  \mathbb{Z} \cdot u(b) \cdot b = A$.
Unfortunately, the assumption $(\ast)$ is not satisfied when $F$ has infinite rank (see 4967770). The claim is also clearly true when $A$ is a direct summand of $F$.

A counterexample can be constructed from this answer. Let $F$ be free of countable rank with basis $e_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (the nonnegative intgers), let
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \langle e_i-(i+1)e_{i+1}\mid i=0,1,2,\ldots\rangle\\
A' &= \langle e_0,A\rangle.
\end{align*}$$
Then $A'\neq A$. If $f\colon F\to \mathbb{Z}$, then letting $u_i=f(e_i)$, we obtain the sequence $u=(u_0,u_1,u_2,\ldots)$ of integers, and $f(A)$ is generated by the gcd of $u_i-(i+1)u_{i+1}$, $i=0,1,2,\ldots$. As proven in the previously linked answer, this subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ always contains $u_0$, i.e.. $f(e_0)\in f(A)$. So $f(A')=f(A)$ always holds.
