Properties of a certain subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ with infinitely many generators
For a sequence of integers $u=(u_0,u_1,\dotsc)$ denote by $I(u) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ the subgroup generated by the integers $u_i - (i+1) u_{i+1}$ for $i \geq 0$.
Assume that an integer $z$ has the property that $z u_0$ lies in $I(u)$ for every sequence $u$. (Equivalently, it is divisible by the gcd of all these generators.) What can we then conclude about $z$? Can we say that $z=0$?
I am not sure. Experiments with some sequences have suggested that $I(u)$ is often generated by $u_0$, in which case we of course cannot conclude anything. But maybe I just couldn't find the good sequences so far.
Context: Notice that $I(u)$ is the image of the corresponding subgroup in the free group of countable rank whose quotient is $\mathbb{Q}$.

@downvoters: please explain what is bad about my question, and how I shall improve it.

I believe that $u_0\in I(u)$ for all $u$, so you can take $z$ to be any integer.
Note that $u_0-n!u_n\in I(u)$ for all $n$; indeed, $I(n)$ contains $u_0-0!u_0$ and $u_0-(1!)u_1$; if it contains $u_0-k!u_k$, then since it also contains $u_k-(k+1)u_{k+1}$ and hence $k!u_k-k!(k+1)u_{k+1}$, it contains their sum, $u_0 - (k+1)!u_{k+1}$.
Lemma 1. $I(u)=(0)$ if and only if $u=(0,0,0,\ldots)$.
Proof. Assume $u$ is not the zero sequence. If $u_0=0$, then taking $k$ with $u_k\neq 0$, we have $u_0-k!u_k\in I(u)$, and $u_0-k!u_k=-k!u_k\neq 0$. If $u_0\neq 0$, then there exists $k\gt 0$ such that $k!\nmid u_0$, and then $u_0-k!u_k\neq 0$ and lies in $I(u)$. $\Box$
Lemma 2. Let $I(u) = n\mathbb{Z}$. If $n\mid ku_k$ for some $k\gt 0$, then $n\mid u_j$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,k-1$.
Proof. Since $n\mid ku_k$ and $n\mid u_{k-1}-ku_k$, then $n\mid u_{k-1}$. Therefore, $n\mid (k-1)u_{k-1}$. Repeating the argument we get $n\mid u_1$ and $n\mid u_0-u_1$, hence $n\mid u_0$. $\Box$
(We can directly show that if $I(u)=n\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\mid ku_k$, then $n\mid u_0$ by noting that $n\mid k!u_k$ and $n\mid u_0-k!u_k$, so $n\mid u_0$).
Now we prove that $u_0\in I(u)$. If $u_0=0$, then this is immediate. If $u_0\neq 0$, then $I(u)\neq \{0\}$, so write $I(u)=n\mathbb{Z}$, with $n\geq 1$. Since $n\mid nu_n$, by Lemma 2 it follows that $n\mid u_j$ with $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, and in particular $n\mid u_0$. Therefore, $u_0\in n\mathbb{Z}=I(u)$, as claimed. $\Box$

Thanks a lot! This gives a counterexample to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4982059/does-the-dual-group-of-a-free-abelian-group-separate-subgroups by the way. Take $F = \langle e_0,e_1,\dotsc \rangle$ and $A=\langle e_i - (i+1) e_{i+1} : i \geq 0\rangle$ and $x = e_0$. Since you did all the work I invite you to post this - what do you think?

@MartinBrandenburg Took me a bit to see that, but sure. I'll post it there.
